# How to pass parameters from php to bash script

Tags: php, bash

I'm trying to change network configuration with the values in the input boxes. When the page loads they show the addresses for the fields and they can be edited by the user. When user hit the **Update** button, they have to be changed as the new values. I couldn't pass the parameters to the server. I have a bash script that changes */etc/network/interfaces* file but I cannot update the file with the correct values.

```
<?php $mask=shell_exec("some grep for netmask' "); ?>
<?php $gateway=shell_exec("some grep for gateway"); ?>
<?php $ip=shell_exec('hostname -I'); ?>
<?php $domain=shell_exec('hostname -d'); ?>

<tr><td>Mask</td><td><input name="mask" value="<? echo $mask ?>"</input></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gateway</td><td><input name="gateway" value="<? echo $gateway ?>"</input></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address</td><td><input name="ip" value="<? echo $ip ?>"</input></td></tr>
<tr><td>Domain</td><td><? echo $domain ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Update</td><td><form name="input" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

so basically you need to modify a file? first thing you need to consider is that php is run by a user and that user should have enough permission to access and modify the bash script file. 
then you just need to read the file, modify the parameters and then write back to it. since we don't have the code for your bash script we can't help you manipulate it but your php code should probably look like this:

```
<?php
$bashscript =file_get_contents("yourbashfile.sh"); // read the bash script
//code to manipulate your bash script with the data in $_POST

file_put_contents("yourbashfile.sh",$bashscript); // and put it back
?>
```